# Next.js state at root but want to use server components

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Say I am building an app where I need some state at the root component, for example:

```
<Dashboard>
  <Form>
  <Modal>
```

Where the Dashboard component has a "modalOpen" state that is set by the Form component and used by the Modal component. Dashboard needs to be a client component because it uses the useState hook, but I want the Form component to be a server component.

It seems to me that the only way I can have a server component be the child of a client component is by [passing the server component to the client component as a prop](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#supported-pattern-passing-server-components-to-client-components-as-props). But then the parent where this is passed has to be a server component. Would the only way to do this be to have another component as the parent of Dashboard with the only purpose being to allow me to pass the Form component as a prop of the Dashboard component? Like this:

```
<Parent> (server)
  <Dashboard> (client)
    <Form> (server)
    <Modal> (client)
```

Or is there a better way to do this?